# Are there any words with different pronunciation but same meaning?

Tags: meaning, pronunciation

Are there any words like can be pronunced in different ways but still have the same meaning in italiano?

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE! Do you mean synonyms?

Comment: No, I mean the same word but people can pronunciate it differently, I'm conducting a study and it is essential for me :)

Comment: For instance, in different regions of Italy?

Comment: I think your question should be reworded so it's clearer what you are asking.

Answer (score 4):

In different regions of Italy there are differences in the way Italians do pronounce many words. I can give you some examples that I took from the book [*Italiano grammatica. Grammatica essenziale della lingua italiana*](https://books.google.es/books/about/Italiano_grammatica_Grammatica_essenzial.html?id=5sxnPgAACAAJ&redir_esc=y)
 by Melina Insolera, published by Zanichelli. According to this book, the word *casa* is pronounced /'kaza/ in the North of Italy (with voiced "s"), while is  /'kasa/ in the Center-South (with voiceless "s"). The word *insalata* instead is /insa'lata/ in the North (with voiceless "s"), but /intsa'lata/ at Rome (with voiceless "z"). The word *roba* is pronounced as *robba*  in many regions of the Center-South, whereas the word *brutto* is often pronounced as *bruto* in the North of Italy. The word *colonna* is pronounced / ko'lɔna/ (with an open "o") at Rome and at many parts of Italy, but not at Florence, where it's pronounced /ko'lonna/ (with a closed "o") due to the Latin origin of the word (it comes from *columna*).

Other examples from this book:

- The word *bene* is pronounced /'bɛne/ at Florence and Rome, but /'bene/ in the North and South of Italy.
- ‎The word *piede* is pronounced /'pjɛde/ at Florence and Rome, but /'pjede/ in the North and South of Italy.
- ‎The word *zio* is pronounced with voiceless "z" /'tsio/ in the Center-South, but with vouced "z" /'dsio/ in the North.

Comment: The /nts/ pronunciation for /ns/ is quite common in Rome dialect.

Answer (score 0):

Credo che occorra distinguere tra "differenze regionali di pronuncia (cfr. [italiano regionale](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-regionale_(Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano)/))" e "pronunce differenti" della stessa parola con signifcato invariato.

Nel primo caso rientrano le pronunce regionali le cui principali divergenze dalla pronuncia standard  consistono nei fenomeni di vocalismo e consononantismo (cfr. Dardano, Trifone, *Grammatica italiana con nozioni di linguistica*, 3a ed., pag.689-690, §17.7).

Come esempio di vocalismo, nel Meridione **scienza** (pronunciato /ˈʃɛnʦa/ nell'italiano standard) viene pronunciato /ˈʃjɛnʦa/ che è errato, in quanto la *i* ha semplice valore diacritico e non va pronunciata.

Come esempio di consonantismo, nel Meridione si ha la sonorizzazione delle consonanti precedute da una nasale: stanco (/'stanko/) viene erratatemente pronunciato /'stango/, tanto (/tanto/) tende ad esser pronunciato /tando/, etc.

Vi sono tantissime differenze di pronuncia legate alla territorialità e basta sfogliare ad esempio il [Dizionario di pronuncia italiana](http://www.dipionline.it/dizionario/) o [il Manuale di pronuncia italiana](http://canipa.net/doku.php?id=en:pdf#manuale_di_pronuncia_italiana) di [Canepari](http://canipa.net/doku.php?id=start) per rendersene conto. Le pronuncia che si discosta dallo "standard" è ovviamente errata, sebbene spesso tollerata. Ad esempio:

- **zio(*)**: pronunciato /'tsio/ è ormai sconsigliato, mentre è corretta la pronuncia /'dsio/;
- **zappa(*)**: consigliato /'dzappa/, mentre è sconsigliato /'tsappa/ (fino ad un tempo addirittura ritenuto l'unica pronuncia corretta)
- **bene**: è corretto /'bɛne/, mentre è errato /'bene/

(*) cfr. *Manuale professionale di dizione e pronuncia* di Carboni Giancarlo, cap. 13, pag. 87-88.

Il linguista Luca Serianni, nella sua *Grammatica Italiana* pag. 14, chiama la pronuncia standard la **pronuncia modello**: "[..omissis..] quasi nessun parlante si sottrae all'impronta della zona d'origine, ... Ciò non vuol dire, però, che non ci sia un *italiano modello*, da identificare, come in altre lingue, in quell che viene realizzato dal parlante che lascia capire il più tardi possibile la propria provenienza regionale e sociale. Un italiano di questo tipo c'è ed è in espansione, benché venga ancora raramente appreso come idioma materno: è la lingua delle scuole di recitazione, degli annunciatori televisivi, dei doppiatori cinematografici, avente alla base il modello colto fiorentino depurato di alcuni tratti idiomatici. **Che una pronuncia normativa esista, possa e debba essere insegnata ci sembra quindi indubbio**."

Nel secondo caso, la questione è più complessa e limitata a poche parole e si tratta di errori che andrebbero emendati. Rientrano in questo caso ad esempio (per la trascrizione fonetica corretta vi prego di ricercare i termini nel [DiPI](http://www.dipionline.it/)):

- il **circuito**: la pronuncia corretta è *circùito*, ma si sente ancora pronunciare, soprattutto nel Nord, *circuìto* (da evitare in quanto errata)
- il **baule**: la pronuncia corretta è *baùle*, ma si sente ancora pronunciare, soprattutto nel Sud, *bàule* (da evitare in quanto errata)
- **edile**: la pronuncia consigliata è *edìle*, ma si sente ancora *édile*

Sulla scia di quanto detto elenco alcune delle parole (in grassetto) con pronucia corretta (la prima in corsivo) e pronuncia differente (dallo standard) e pertanto scosigliata/errata (la seconda):

- **appendice**: *appendìce* (pr. corretta), appèndice (pr. sconsigliata/errata)
- **amaca**: *àmaca*, amàca
- **autodromo**: *autòdromo*, autodròmo
- **bocciolo**: *bocciòlo*, bòcciolo
- **bolscevico**: *bolscevìco*, bolscèvico
- **caduco**: *cadùco*, càduco
- **calligugo**: *callìfugo*, callifùgo
- **cosmopolita**: *cosmopolìta*, cosmopòlita
- **cuculo**: *cucùlo*, cùculo
- **dissipo**: *dìssipo*, dissìpo
- **fortuito**: *fortùito*, fortuìto

e così via.

Potete trovare un elenco in *Manuale professionale di dizione e pronuncia* di Carboni Giancarlo oppure nel [link della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/vademecum-sullaccento-indicarlo-pronunciarlo).

Vi sono inoltre altre *parole per le quali esistono pronunce diverse ma entrambe corrette*. Ad esempio

- **guaina** ha la pronuncia comune /ˈɡwaina/ e la pronuncia  /ɡwaˈina/ (denota l'intenzione di dar sfoggio di cultura! ma non è aulica né colta)
- **elaboro** ha la pronuncia comune /e'laboro/ e la pronuncia aulica /ela'boro/ (rappresentativa soprattutto della lingua poetica o arcaica)
- **zaffiro** pronunciato /'dzaffiro/ seguendo l'accentazione greca e /dzaf'firo/ seguendo l'accentazione latina.

Il sito di [Canepari](http://canipa.net/doku.php?id=start) e le relative pubblicazioni approfondiscono il tema per chi vuole sapere di più.

Consiglio infine il [DOP - Dizionario multimediale e multiligue d'Ortografia e di Pronunzia](http://www.dizionario.rai.it/) seppur provvisorio ed incompleto.

Per chi volesse esercitarsi con la [dizione](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dizione_della_lingua_italiana) dell'[italiano standard](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/italiano-standard_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), oltre al manuale sopra citato, consiglio il volume di [**Canepàri e Giovannelli**, *La buona pronuncia
italiana del terzo millennio*](http://www.aracneeditrice.it/pdf/9788854826915.pdf)

Comment: Molto interessante, ma non capisco perché una pronuncia regionale diversa dallo "standard" debba essere considerata "ovviamente errata". Cito dal libro *Italiano grammatica. Grammatica essenziale della lingua italiana* dal quale ho tratto i miei esempi: «Lo straniero che studia l'italiano deve essere preparato a uno sforzo supplementare, proprio perché l'italiano, mentre ha uno standard scritto altamente codificato, manca concretamente di uno standard per il parlato, nel quale si riflettono di necessità  le molte differenti pronunce regionali».

Comment: Nella mia lingua, il catalano, accade lo stesso: ci sono diverse pronunce dipendendo dalle regioni. E guai a me, che ho la pronuncia di Barcellona, si oso dire a una persona proveniente da un'altra regione che la sua pronuncia del catalano è errata!

Comment: Un altro dettaglio a commentare: su Italian.SE abbiamo la [regola](https://italian.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6) di rispondere in inglese a una domanda scritta in inglese e in italiano a una domanda in italiano.

Comment: Sul concetto di standard ci sono ampie discussioni, tant'è che Canepari la chiama pronuncia naturale,  piuttosto che pronuncia standard, ossia "buona pronuncia italiana di quei suoni, di quelle intonazioni, di quegli elementi così diversi da quelli che normalmente sentiamo nel parlato quotidiano."  In sintesi, ma l'argomento meriterebbe maggiore approfondiment, si può dire che l'italiano standard è quello che si insegna nelle scuole di dizione. Non conosco la Grammatica citata, ma i più grandi linguisti italiani (Canepari, Serianni, ecc.) sono sostanzialmente d'accordo sul punto.

Comment: Non conoscevo la regola, ma credo che allora bisognerebbe correggere il "we should" in "we must". Ne terrò conto per il futuro.

Comment: Consiglio il seguente [articolo](http://www.laricerca.loescher.it/lingua-italiana/269-la-pronuncia-standard-dellitaliano.html)

Comment: Per quanto concerne le varianti regionali, nessuno mai andrà a dire all'atro che la sua pronuncia è sbagliata (a meno di evidenti errori tipo bàule al Sud invece che baùle..). Di certo però non sarà accettato per la recitazione a teatro o la lettura del notiziario in tv...a meno che non faccia un corso di dizione..di italiano standard o neutro che dir si voglia.

Comment: Ad esempio "scopa" viene pronunciato  ʃkopa nel sud invece che sˈkopa. Sebbene sia errato, nessuno lo correggerà in quanto evidentemente dipendente dalla regionalità. Tuttavia non lo si sentirà mai in TV, a meno che non sia un film ambientato in Sicilia...

Comment: Capisco che in certe situazioni sia raccomandabile l'uso di uno standard per facilitare la comunicazione (anche qui c'è "l'Institut d'Estudis Catalans" che define un catalano standard per la stessa ragione, che ammette però un certo grado di flessibilità), ma questo mi sembra diverso dall'affermare che le varianti regionali siano "errate".

Comment: Credo dipenda dalla definizione di "errato". Per me "errato" è ciò che non soddisfa la regola dettata in questo caso dallo standard, a meno che non si voglia classificarle come eccezioni estremamente ampie...

Comment: Sono piuttosto perplesso sull'affermazione che la pronuncia “èdile” sia consigliata. Da chi? Il Treccani dice che è “comune ma non corretta”; il DiPi ha “edìle” come prima pronuncia. Similmente per “zio” e “zappa” il DOP dà solo la pronuncia /ts/.

Comment: Per edile avevo invertito io gli accenti. Adesso ho rettificato. Il DOP (che occorre ammetterlo è lento ad essere aggiornato) fornisce la pronuncia tradizionale che è fornita dal DiPI come la più consigliata un tempo. In 2 manuali di dizione e nel DiPI ho trovato /dz/ per zio e zappa.

Comment: Riporto quanto si trova nel maulae di dizione di Carboni pag. 87: "La pronuncia sonora della "zeta" iniziale è oggi riconosciuta e accettata in quanto coincide con il modello di pronuncia 'moderno'. [..omissis..] Lo scenario che ne deriva è quindi contraddittorio: da un lato gli strumenti di consultazione normativa continuano a riportare la pronncia con il suono sordo (p.e. zio, zappa, zucchero), dall'altro però tale pronuncia nell'italiano parlato è pressoché inesistente. "

Comment: continuo dal commento precedente: "Nell'italiano contemporaneo "z" ha pronuncia sonora quando è iniziale seguita da due vocali.[omissis] sono veramente pochi gli italiani che realizzano le parole zappa, zio, zucchero con il suono sordo. Questa pronuncia assume di conseguenza un sentore arcaico o persino dialettale."